# Can't get Node App Started (server.js, possible Babel issue?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

I'm trying to get my Node application to start with npm start. The application is crashing on start and I do not know why. I am really new to Node and all things full-stack. Can anybody make sense of whats going on?

When I run npm start --verbose I get this:

```
hunterhawley@hunter-test:~$ npm start --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/home/hunterhawley/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.1/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/home/hunterhawley/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.1/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'start',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@6.7.0
npm info using node@v11.10.1
npm verb config Skipping project config: /home/hunterhawley/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
npm verb run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
npm info lifecycle mern-starter@2.0.0~prestart: mern-starter@2.0.0
npm info lifecycle mern-starter@2.0.0~start: mern-starter@2.0.0

> mern-starter@2.0.0 start /home/hunterhawley
> cross-env BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 NODE_ENV=development nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 1.17.5
[nodemon] reading config ./nodemon.json
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] or send SIGHUP to 31462 to restart
[nodemon] ignoring: .git node_modules/**/node_modules
[nodemon] watching: /home/hunterhawley/server/**/* Intl
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
[nodemon] forking
[nodemon] child pid: 31475
[nodemon] watching 37 files
/home/hunterhawley/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:558
      throw err;
      ^

SyntaxError: /home/hunterhawley/server/server.js: Unexpected token (164:8)
  162 |     const store = configureStore({
  163 |       app: {
> 164 |         ...initialAppState,
      |         ^
  165 |         user: { ...req.session.user },
  166 |       },
  167 |     });
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (/home/hunterhawley/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/hunterhawley/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseIdentifier (/home/hunterhawley/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4332:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parsePropertyName (/home/hunterhawley/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4156:96)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseObj (/home/hunterhawley/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4045:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/home/hunterhawley/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3719:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/home/hunterhawley/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3494:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/home/hunterhawley/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3474:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/home/hunterhawley/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3404:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/home/hunterhawley/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3381:19)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

So it seems to me that this is a babel issue. I can attach my index.js or any other file if that will help you figure this out. Thank you!

EDIT: Also I just wanted to add that the install process (though it took some work) went smoothly, and I have MongoDB running in another terminal window, which for this application is needed. I've also tried going direct and running node index.js but that didn't get me anywhere either.

EDIT 2: Here is what I got when installing the plugin given in answer 1

```
npm WARN babel-plugin-webpack-loaders@0.9.0 requires a peer of webpack@>=1.12.9 <3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin@0.1.0 requires a peer of webpack@^1.4.0-beta6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1 requires a peer of webpack@^1.9.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2 requires a peer of webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-server@2.11.2 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-manifest-plugin@1.3.2 requires a peer of webpack@1 || 2 || 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.3.4 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@7.2.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN mern-starter@2.0.0 No repository field.

+ @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.3.4
added 3 packages from 1 contributor and audited 20460 packages in 22.759s
```

EDIT 3: Adding my webpack.config.babel.js file

```
var cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext');
var postcssFocus = require('postcss-focus');
var postcssReporter = require('postcss-reporter');

var cssModulesIdentName = '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  cssModulesIdentName = '[hash:base64]';
}

module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
      'client',
      'node_modules',
    ],
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?localIdentName=' + cssModulesIdentName + '&modules&importLoaders=1&sourceMap!postcss-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$/i,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
      },
    ],
  },
  postcss: () => [
    postcssFocus(),
    cssnext({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'IE > 10'],
    }),
    postcssReporter({
      clearMessages: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: what's your node version?

Comment: So I've tried it with 11.10.1 and 6.0.0, and the reason I've tried with 6.0.0 is because the guy who wrote this with/for me (I hired him, and now I'm trying to learn Node myself) has the production server running in 6.0.0 for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution is update to Node v8.3 or higher...

*"As of Node v8.3, object rest/spread is available without the need for any transpilation."*

If you're transpiling using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), as you mentioned, then you'll need to add [a plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread) to polyfill support for [Object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). In your `.babelrc` file add...

```
"plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
]
```

And you'll need to install this plugin obviously...

```
npm i -D @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
//OR
yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread --dev
```

*NOTE: This will require `"@babel/core": "^7.0.0"`*

Here is an example of how to configure your `.babelrc` file for node transpiling...

```
  {
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/env", {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }]
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  }
```

You can also add the plugin directly within you Webpack config *(webpack.config.babel.js)*...

```
loaders: [
 {
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
      plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread']
    }
  }
 }
]
```

Example of specific packages *(in package.json)* I'm currently using in a Node/Babel project, which may help upgrading to `Babel ^7.0.0`...

```
"devDependencies": {
 "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
 "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
 "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.3.1",
 "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.4",
 "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
 "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
 "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
 "babel-jest": "^24.0.0",
 "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
 "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0"
}
```

Comment: When I installed the plugin I got something that I'll add as an edit in my answer

Comment: Oh ya I can probably guess your issue. You'll need to be running something close to `"@babel/core": "^7.2.2"`.

Comment: Also I was using 11.10.1 when I ran this the first time and it didn't go through. And I'm sorry, this is probably really dumb, but I don't have a .babelrc file. Isn't there another place I can add the plugin reference? I have a webpack.config.babel.js

Comment: Hmm if you were running `Node ^11.0.0` then you shouldn't have had a problem so there may have been something else wrong, but with your current configuration this should work, then we can troubleshoot further. It should actually be almost the same syntax as in the `.babelrc` file, but can you add the `webpack.config.babel.js` to your question?

Comment: Added @cantuket

Comment: Sorry that was *(probably)* unnecessary. Just try adding the above `.babelrc` file in the root of your project and Webpack should pick it up

Comment: Doing that right now. Will comment again with the results

Comment: You can also add the plugin directly within your `webpack.config.babel.js`. Just updated my answer. You'll need to install `babel-loader` first though... `npm i -D babel-loader`

Comment: I did all that and it didn't work. I'm trying to run the npm install again and seeing if that makes a difference.

Comment: Unfortunately re-installing didn't help either

Comment: Unfortunately things may get a little tricky since you're now updating everything to `Babel ^7.0.0`. I can't do much to help you there, but try deleting your old `node_modules` directory before installing again... `rm -r node_modules`. I'll add the exact modules I'm currently using for a Babel/Node project which may help. Other wise, just keep following `npm`s prompts and upgrading the respective dependencies in the errors.

Comment: Thank you. You've been a huge help and I'll post here if/when I get this figured out. Can't thank you enough though.

Comment: No problem, happy to help! Build tools is my least favorite area of JS development and inevitably takes a bunch of trial-&-error to get configured properly, but then can save you tons of time... until they update something big